# C# Как поместить на передний план второе окно c одинаковым pid

Tags: c#, google-chrome

Собственно вопрос в заголовке. Чтобы было понятнее вот картинка.

[image: На передний план]

Что пробовал:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern IntPtr SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
```

Проблема в том что как бы оба эти окна являются одним процессом, с одним pid и на передний план выволакивается либо ничего либо первое окно.
Подозреваю что можно как то по названию окна сделать, но как быть если название меняется? Помогите кто чем может)

Comment: `SetForegroundWindow` принимает handle окна, а не pid. Может покажете как Вы его вызываете?

Comment: Посмотрите вопрос на английском о том как получить хэндлы для окон по процессу: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79111/net-c-getting-child-windows-when-you-only-have-a-process-handle-or-pid

Comment: `Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
IntPtr i; //change this to IntPtr
i = proc.MainWindowHandle; 
ShowWindow(i, 3);
SetForegroundWindow(i); //set to topmost`

Comment: Ну да, Вы передаете главное окно (`proc.MainWindowHandle`) вместо этого нужно перебрать дочерние и выбрать нужное. Напишите еще как Вы собираетесь определять нужное окно? Чем оно отличается от других?

Comment: По большому счету ничем кроме порядкового номера. Но попробую взять из названия)